# PyQt + custom QML object: Cannot read property 'x' of null

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qml

Using PyQt + QML, it's pretty intuitive.  However I'm a little stumped.  The qml binding 'window.current.summary' complains with the error in the title `Cannot read property 'summary' of null`

Python:

```
class DataPoint(QObject):
    ....
    @pyqtProperty('QString')
    def summary(self):
        print("Retrieving summary: ", self._datapoint.summary)
        return self._datapoint.summary


class Weather(QObject):
    ....
    @pyqtProperty(DataPoint, notify=forecastChanged)
    def current(self):
        return DataPoint(self._forecast.currently())

    @pyqtProperty('QString', notify=forecastChanged)
    def current_summary(self):
        return self._forecast.currently().summary
```

QML:

```
Weather {
    id: w1
}

Text {
    ...
    id: current_temp
    text: w1.current.summary
    // text: w1.current_summary // this works
}
```

Think I've missed something obvious here.  I've verified that the 'current' property is indeed interrogated.  `Retrieving summary` is never seen, indicating to me that DataPoint itself is never interrogated.  How do we get that QML `w1.current.summary` to bind as expected?

Comment: you could publish the part that launches the .qml and the remaining code to be an [MCVE], there could be the error.

Comment: roger that.  I couldn't think of a way to keep it concise (minimal) but I'll put in some extra effort to see

Comment: For example, publish the class DataPoint and Weather, the main.py and the .qml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've discovered the problem.  The lines:

```
@pyqtProperty(DataPoint, notify=forecastChanged)
    def current(self):
        return DataPoint(self._forecast.currently())
```

Are the culprit.  Changing to

```
@pyqtProperty(DataPoint, notify=forecastChanged)
    def current(self):
        return self._datapoint
```

Where `self._datapoint` is previously set to DataPoint solves it.

I conclude from this that the memory management in Python is such that temporary objects are very temporary indeed, more like C++ than C# - and the temporary-`DataPoint` immediately vanishes from scope and memory on return of `current()`

Comment: I have noticed more complex scenarios which don't demand the "self._datapoint" part.  So I think there is something incomplete or erroneous about my conclusion.  The fix *does* work though